# How to create "otherButtonTitles"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have the AlertView working perfectly with a "cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"" and "otherButtonTitles:nil". My question is how to get other buttons.

When I only change the "otherButtonTitles:@"2nd Button"", then the iPhone simulator just crashes out of the app and into the homescreen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to end your method call like this:

... `cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Button1Title", @"Button2Title", nil];`

This is the same pattern you see in String formatting, where the list of arguments can be of any length.  Usually the argument list is then nil-terminated.  Don't forget the nil.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly [like Kevin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955878/642706), but as an addendum to that, you can also assign target-actions to the other buttons.

When you instantiate the `UIAlertView`, set the `delegate` argument to `self`, then add the following method to your object:

```
-(void) alertView: ( UIAlertView *) alertView 
         clickedButtonAtIndex: ( NSInteger ) buttonIndex {
      // do stuff
      // if you want the alert to close, just call [ alertView release ]   
}
```

`

Comment: How do I control which button will activate this method though? I tried it out and no matter which button I press (including Cancel), it will always run this method. Ohhh! Do I set a conditional inside this method to check which button to do stuff for?

Comment: Like `[ self performSelector: [ buttonActions objectAtIndex: buttonIndex ] ];`
This would work if you had an array of selectors called 'buttonActions' -- just an example.

Comment: why would you bother with that, instead of of using switch(buttonIndex) in the delegate callback?

Comment: switch(buttonIndex){
    case 0:
          [self oneMethod];
          break;
    case 1:
          [self anotherMethod];
          break;
    default:
          break;
}

Comment: use the \`at the beginning and a \` at the end

Comment: ( i escaped those so u could see them ).

Comment: and, executor21, it was just an example, i know it could work that way, but my example is quite a bit more dynamic with less code.

Comment: Be aware that `clickedButtonAtIndex` occurs while the UIAlertView is **still on-screen**. To react *after* the UIAlertView has been dismissed, has left the screen, and is then safe to push views to your nav controller, use [`didDismissWithButtonIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:).